# Get text field data from PDF

Tags: php, pdf, import, extract

I'm looking for a way to be able to extract the text fields from a PDF. I have gone through many many posts on here and other sites with regards to extracting this information but a lot of them are around 5 years old or even older so looking to see if there is something more up to date?

I have a form that we send to our customers so that they can fill out warranty claims. This is a PDF document with fields that they can fill in, save the form and email it into the warranty department. The warranty department then manually take this form and enter it onto our intranet system. I would like to automate this so that they can upload the emailed PDF and it will populate the database quickly rather than having someone manually key in the information, quite often with errors!

This needs to be available in PHP.

Comment: A 3 seconds search in Google returned this: https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk

Comment: I have never been able to get composer to work with anything. was hoping there was another way.